# How to download a webpage for offline viewing on Nexus 7

Tags: android, tablet, nexus-7

I have a webpage that I would like to view when I am not in a WIFI area on my Nexus 7 tablet.
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sorry, but this is offtopic here.

Comment: did u mean you have webpage with fix data or any webpage to see offline ?

Comment: Any webpage. Particularly one with music on it with html 5 audio tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an application like [Pocket](http://getpocket.com).

Answer (score 0):

One solution to download the website was using HTTrack. I can copy it to the Nexus 7 and I can open it using something like ES File Explorer.

Another solution is if you have the Kindle app on your Nexus, it's easy to send a web page from your PC to your Nexus Kindle app.

Third solution is to use application Pocket.