# how to download a page in android

Tags: java, android, search, html

I am developing an android app in which the app has to download a webpage..for that how the code has to write.if any one know please help.

The page I needed to download and view in webview is  [this](http://www.androidaspect.com/)

I refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) to achieve my goal . but i ddn't get a proper answer...

Comment: I am not sure but take a look at it http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers

Answer (score 1):

You can use pocket:

[Click here.](http://getpocket.com/)

The following can be helpful.
[How to download a webpage for offline viewing on Nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322978/how-to-download-a-webpage-for-offline-viewing-on-nexus-7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample code for download a html source code.

```
 public void getHtml() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
 {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.androidaspect.com/");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          response.getEntity().getContent()
        )
      );

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      result += line + "\n";

    }

 }
```

Be suer to use it with AsyncTask and not on the main thread. And don't forget for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

permission.